# Car wont start gas issue started this mess

Tags: starting

Car ran out of gas yesterday. Put in five gallons it went 1 mile cut off. When it finally started again was hopping like a rabbit. Got it home finally . now it won't turn over no dash lights no click no sound at all dead.

Comment: First thing to do is check the battery voltage.

Comment: 2 different problems. The rough running was contaminated fuel-water in bottom of tank, or solid crud being dragged out of tank and clogging filter or piercing filter and clogging injectors.  The dead car is a flat battery, blown main fuse or loose battery terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have 2 different issues here:

1. Rough running after running out of fuel: there are sediments on the bottom of your tank, when you run out of fuel your pump sucks these up and they clog up the fuel system. These sediments are caught by your fuel filter, which is usually a cheap and quick fix. Replace or have the filter replaced, if it's still running rough you'll need more troubleshooting
2. No dash lights: either your battery has run out or you have a bad connection on your battery terminals. If you have a multimeter check your battery voltage, if the voltage is good, i.e. 12.5 volts or above then your battery terminals have likely gunked up or come loose which would be a simple coincidence. If your battery voltage is low then maybe in all the trouble you left your lights on, and drained your battery, or you ran your battery down by having to constantly start it up all the way home. If you don't have a multimeter then check the battery terminals and if they are good get a jump start and see if it works

Comment: Along with sediment ,there may have been water. Ethanol addition ,required in US absorbs water, But, with some quantity of water, a second phase forms, an alcohol-water phase, Droplets of this second phase mixed into gasoline could cause your symptoms.

Comment: Water at the bottom of the tank sounds like the most likely cause.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the water theory as once the tank was filled up the issue should have resolved quickly once the water ran through the system.